# Shell Model of the Nucleus Holes

Tags: nuclear-physics

Can someone help me how to determine whether there is a hole or a particle in a given shell? Is it as simple as if the number of particles is close to the number of the maximum particles in each shell, then we have a hole, whereas if the number of the particles is far smaller than the max number of particles this shell can hold then it's a particle?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially yes. In certain cases, considering a hole instead of many particles simplifies the problem greatly.